# Android 4...do or do not

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I was wondering if there's any compelling reason to shift my three-quarter complete app targeted at Android 2.2 thru Honeycomb (using the Google I/O app as a guide)  to Android 4...abandoning the current development track.

For example, developing with the 4.0 SDK won't allow for native actionbar support in older phones, correct?

I can't seem to decide if it would be worth going back to the drawing board...

I appreciate any examples/advice.

EDIT:
Thank you to those who commented and tried to help and gave me valuable feedback...and thank you Charles and gang for letting me know what an insignificant question and waste of time it was...

Comment: Check out the compatible library ... action bar will be support

Comment: If you do go 4.0, and you have a custom build.xml, set aside an afternoon to convert it to make it work in SDK 4.0

Comment: @xDragonZ i'll have to look at the compat library. I didn't realize it was updated as well.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending how long it would take you to finish the app, just finish it. Currently there are no devices with android 4.0; [This](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) is the current situation; and to put that into perspective a bit more I've got an app on the market now that has roughly 85% 2.x users, and 15% 3.x users.

Your app will run on 4.0 if compiled against lower api's, there is the compatibility library that gives fragments etc to 2.x, and there are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495007/verifyerror-deploying-on-api-1-6) to do backward compatibility otherwise even when targeting 4.0. You can adopt these things fairly easily, so going back to the drawing board at this time of development to my opinion isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking more audience for your app then you can wait until Ice Cream gets matured; just keep in mind that Android 2.2 + 2.3 currently gives you >83% of devices. On the other hand I just remembered Jobs' favorite quotation of Wayne Gretzky:  'I skate to where the puck is going to be, not where it has been.'

Answer (score 0):

Don't
You will have a small market for a long time. (well, long is relative I guess)
I think is better to finish 2.2 + version and then start with 4.0