# java.lang.VerifyError and getActionBar() on Android 1.6

Tags: android, android-actionbar, verifyerror

In my application I'm using this code:

```
@TargetApi(14)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=14) {
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

But when I run it in emulator with Android 1.6 I get this error:

```
04-24 09:01:16.562: E/dalvikvm(922): Could not find method com.myname.myapp.MainActivity.getActionBar, referenced from method com.myname.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate
04-24 09:01:16.562: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1014: Lcom/myname/myapp/MainActivity;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
04-24 09:01:16.562: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x0155
04-24 09:01:16.562: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY:  rejected Lcom/myname/myapp/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
04-24 09:01:16.572: W/dalvikvm(922): Verifier rejected class Lcom/myname/myapp/MainActivity;
04-24 09:01:16.572: W/dalvikvm(922): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/myname/myapp/MainActivity;)
04-24 09:01:16.572: D/AndroidRuntime(922): Shutting down VM
04-24 09:01:16.572: W/dalvikvm(922): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
04-24 09:01:16.572: E/AndroidRuntime(922): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922): java.lang.VerifyError: com.myname.myapp.MainActivity
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
04-24 09:01:16.582: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I remove line getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false); it working fine. How can I fix it without this line removing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VerifyError deploying on API 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495007/verifyerror-deploying-on-api-1-6)

Answer (score 1):

use `android-support-v4.jar` its just like adding ActionBar after that hide that.

Hope you have used [actiobarShareLock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for < 11 API.